# Can I useEffect inside a loop sure to be of constant dimension?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a functional React component (more a proxy to a non-React object) like so:

```
function ProxyComponent({onEvent1, onEvent2, onEvent3 ...}){
  useEffect(()=>{
    someObject?.on('event1', onEvent2);
    return someObject?.off('event1', onEvent2);
  },[onEvent2, someObject])

  useEffect(()=>{
    someObject?.on('event1', onEvent1);
    return someObject?.off('event1', onEvent1);
  },[onEvent1, someObject])
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Except that there are a lot of events, and there's an obvious pattern here. So I'd like to do this:

```
function ProxyComponent(props){
  const events = {
    'event1': props.onEvent1 ?? null,
    ...
    'event20': props.onEvent20 ?? null
  }
  

  for (const [name, handler] of Object.entries(events)) {
    useEffect(()=>{
      handler && someObject?.on(name, handler);
      return handler && someObject?.off(name, handler);
    },[handler, someObject])
  }

}
```

The [rules of hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) make it clear that this usage is not supported, but I'd like to know **how I can automate this pattern while still being within the rules of hook** [This is the main question]

Notes:

1. The `.on` and `.off` methods create network requests so it's best to call them as little as possible.
2. Moving the loop inside the useEffect creates two complications:

   a. A very long dependency array [onEvent1, ..., onEvent20]. I highly doubt that `[...Object.values(events)]` works.

   b. Every change in a single handler causes several `.off`s and undoes it with new `.on`s again. Apart from the inefficiency, in my particular case, I'd like to avoid this because of note#1.

Comment: The question is how often do you want this to run? If you have multiple requests it's better to Promisify them and use Promise.all() or something similar. Network requests in for loops are a pain in the ass to debug.

Comment: Can `someObject` change (if so, where from - is it a prop?), or is it in the dependency array only for exhaustive-deps?

Comment: @GeorgeMakroglou ideally just once at the start of the program. network requests pile up when the useeffect runs a lot of times doing and undoing and redoing the handlers.

Comment: @CertainPerformance someObject is instantiated in another useEffect dependent on the token prop.

Comment: If you want it to run only once you can leave the dependency array empty and supress the warning like this
useEffect(() => {
   //your for loop here
}, 
//eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
[])

Your code is very generic and I don't know what is in each listener but you can give it a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that calling `useEffect` inside a loop is OK if the number of iterations is absolutely static. The following doesn't throw an error:

```js
const App = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log('an effect');
      }, []);
    }
    return 'foo';
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<App />)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

and the point of the rule is:

> By following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders. That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks between multiple useState and useEffect calls.

which a static loop fulfills. Loops *often* have conditions that will cause them to execute different numbers of times, which is probably why "Don't use hooks inside loops" is there - but the blanket statement is not quite as precise as React actually requires.

So, going with your

```
for (const [name, handler] of Object.entries(events)) {
    useEffect(()=>{
```

could be fine - the only issue would be with linters.

Setting up an alternative approach is possible, just somewhat convoluted. You need to emulate the behavior of `useEffect` by comparing the current value of something to a previous value, without using hooks in a loop. One option would be to put the handers (passed by props) into state. Each render, go through the props and check for any inequalities with what's in state. If there are, resubscribe.

Comment: That seems to be the case for me. It works as expected, no bugs so far.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a helper component, like the following

```
function Helper({eventName, eventHandler, someObject}) {
    useEffect(() => {
        someObject?.on(eventName, eventHandler);
        return someObject?.off(eventName, eventHandler);
    }, [eventName, eventHandler, someObject])
}
```

Then, you can call this component inside your `ProxyComponent`, inside of a loop:

```
const events = {
    'event1': props.onEvent1 ?? null,
    ...
    'event20': props.onEvent20 ?? null
}
return (
    <>
        {Object.keys(events).map(event => (
            <Helper eventName={event} eventHandler={events[event]} someObject={someObject} />
        ))}
    </>
)
```

To prevent calling Helper component on each prop change of the parent, you can export it with [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)

Comment: That's an interesting idea, I like it. Avoid the hook-inside-loop issue by moving the loop outside of a component.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single effect, but you'll have to memoize and compare dependencies manually:

```js
function ProxyComponent (props) {
  const previousEntriesRef = useRef([]);
  const previousSomeObjectRef = useRef(someObject);

  const eventHandlerMap = {
    'event1': props.onEvent1 ?? null,
    'event2': props.onEvent2 ?? null,
    // etc...
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const cleanupFns = [];
    const currentEntries = Object.entries(eventHandlerMap);
    const someObjectPrevious = previousSomeObjectRef.current;

    for (const [index, [name, handler]] of currentEntries.entries()) {
      const [namePrevious, handlerPrevious] =
        previousEntriesRef.current[index] ?? [];

      if (
        Object.is(name, namePrevious)
        && Object.is(handler, handlerPrevious)
        && Object.is(someObject, someObjectPrevious)
      ) continue;

      if (!handler) continue;
      someObject?.on(name, handler);
      cleanupFns.push(() => someObject?.off(name, handler));
    }

    previousEntriesRef.current = currentEntries;
    previousSomeObjectRef.current = someObject;

    return () => {
      for (const fn of cleanupFns) fn();
    };
  });
}
```