# why do we need to put the onViewableItemsChanged prop inside a useRef hook in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, use-ref

```
      const _onViewableItemsChanged = useRef(({ viewableItems }) => {
                setCurrentPageIndex(viewableItems[0].index ?? 0);
       });
```

So, I found this code online that gets the index of the currently viewed page inside a FlatLisk but I'm having a hard time understanding why we should put it inside the useRef.

Comment: @CertainPerformance https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Efy48Uoa4RM

Answer (score 3):

The code that is used is actually:

```
const onViewableItemsChanged = useRef(({ viewableItems }) => {
    setCurrentPageIndex(viewableItems[0].index ?? 0);
}).current;
```

which should make the intent of this approach clearer. The callback passed to `useRef` is called only once, when the component mounts, and the object returned is stable across mounts. But with this code, the value inside the object is extracted immediately with the `.current`. Essentially, what this does is create a **stable instance variable** for a given mount of this component.

Compare with, for example:

```
const onViewableItemsChanged = ({ viewableItems }) => {
    setCurrentPageIndex(viewableItems[0].index ?? 0);
};
```

This is pretty similar to the approach with `useRef`, except that the function is created anew each time the component re-renders. [There are no stale closures to worry about here](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/), because the only outside variable referenced inside the function is `setCurrentPageIndex`, and `setCurrentPageIndex` is stable across renders.

Whether a function is re-created or not generally only matters in relation to child components that use the function. When you pass down a new function as a prop to a child component, a decently designed child component will detect that change, remove whatever functionality was using the *old* function, and reattach the functionality using the new function. For example, if the child component has:

```
const Child = ({ fn }) => (
  <button onClick={fn}>click</button>
);
```

Then whenever the `fn` prop passed down by the parent changes, the child must remove the previous click listener from the button (the previous `fn`), and add a new listener (the new `fn` that was just passed down).

If the child component subscribes to a non-DOM event with the prop, handling the changing of the prop could be [more difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72778230/9515207) to handle.

So, it could be desirable to pass down a stable prop if possible - but if the child components are already designed properly, it almost certainly won't matter either way.

Note that an identical approach to create an instance variable can be:

```
const [onViewableItemsChanged] = useState(() => ({ viewableItems }) => {
    setCurrentPageIndex(viewableItems[0].index ?? 0);
});
```

This has the same effect as:

```
const onViewableItemsChanged = useRef(({ viewableItems }) => {
    setCurrentPageIndex(viewableItems[0].index ?? 0);
}).current;
```

because the value in the argument that gets put into the state only occurs when the component mounts.

Comment: thank you for your explanation ! but i still can't get the difference between the 2nd code block that you wrote and the 4th one. or more specifically i didn't quite understand the 4th one. how does that state deal with re-renders ?

Comment: Imagine you're passing a function down to a child component, and the child attaches the function as scroll listener. The child might do `useEffect(() => { container.addEventListener('scroll', props.onScroll); }, [])` - but that would only account for the onScroll passed on mount. If the prop changes over re-renders, it would have to account for that change and remove the old one. `useEffect(() => { container.addEventListener('scroll', props.onScroll); return () => container.removeEventListener('scroll', props.onScroll); }, [props.onScroll]);`

Comment: If the prop changes, a child needs to be able to account for the changes. If the prop will never change, that makes things easier for the child.